# Data of dropdown in form not inserting in databse only deparment values are not inserting

Tags: php, html, database, insert, dropdown

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Registration system PHP and MySQL</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
  <div class="header">
    <h2>Register</h2>
  </div>
  <?php
  $server="localhost";
  $userid ="root";
  $Password = "";
  $myDB = "project";

  $con = mysqli_connect($server,$userid,$Password,$myDB);

  // Check connection
  if (!$con) {
      die("Connection failed: ".mysqli_connect_error());
  } else {
      echo "Connected successfully";
  }
  ?>
  <form method="POST" action="test.php">
    Name:<br>
    <input type="text" name="name"><br><br>
    Department:<br>
    <label for="department">Choose a department:</label>
    <select>
      <option>Select</option>
  <?php 

  $sqlq = "SELECT * FROM users";
  $result = mysqli_query($con, $sqlq);
  while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo '<option>'.$row['department'].'</option>';
  }
  ?>
  </select>
  <br><br>
  Email:<br>
  <input type="text" name="email"><br><br>
  <button type="submit" name="register_btn">Register</button>
</div>
<p>Already a member? Sign in</p>
  </form>
  <?php

  if(isset($_POST['register_btn'])){  
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $department= $_POST['Department'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    
    $query="INSERT INTO `users`
                            (`id`,`name`,`department`, `email`, `password`) 
                    VALUES ('','$name','$department','$email','abcd')";
    
    if(mysqli_query($con, $query)){
        echo "Records inserted successfully.";
    } else {
        echo "ERROR: Could not able to execute $sql. " . mysqli_error($con);
    }
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

All the data are inserted into my database except  department from the dropdown menu.please help me if possible any please
All the data are inserted into my database except  department from the dropdown menu.please help me if possible any please All the data are inserted into my database except  department from the dropdown menu.please help me if possible any please

Comment: id, name ,email ,and password are inserting successfully except department

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php). 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: is there any alternating way to copy the value of drop down and take into the text value and then send to the database

Answer (score 1):

You have to give the `<select>` dropdown a name. If an input field has no name the browser will not even attempt to send the value to the backend.

Also as you have a `<label>` using the `for=""` attribute the `<select>` also needs an `id="department"`

```
Department:<br>
<label for="department">Choose a department:</label>
<select id="department" name="department">
```

Comment: above same code   after clicking on register btn 
 date is inserted and on refreshing the browser inserts more date automatically

Comment: Yes that will happen when you use the same script for HTML and PHP